# linqpad query to connect two entities in odata

Tags: linqpad

I am using linqpad. I have an ODATA connected. The entities are listed in left pane with relationships. There are two entities called Products and Customers. I have to get all the product id starting with pid and names of all customers startin with b. There is a relationship between both. Product is a child of customer. How do I do? I am trying since two days but unable to figure it out. Anyone could help?
this is the base code. i dont no what to do further.

```
    from p in products
    where p.ProductId.StartsWith("Pid")
    from c in customers
    where c.Name.StartsWith("B")
    select new
    {
        p.Pid,
        c.Name
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please specify how you want the relation between the two entities to affect the result of the query? Do you expect the above to only returns products (with ID starting with a given value) and then only the customers for those products which name starts with a certain value?

Such a query is not expressible in OData unfortunately. You could request all products which ID starts with a specific value, and all the related customers. And then filter the customers on the client.

For example this will get you all the products which ID starts with a certain value and all their customers:

```
from p in products
where p.ProductId.StartsWith("Pid")
select new Product
{
   ProductId = p.ProductId,
   Customers = p.Customers
};
```